# Z3 gives no or wrong solution when there are a right solution

Tags: z3

I am writing a problem with BitVecs as I have to do bit-blasting later. I have a sum constraint. To avoid overflow solutions, e.g. x0 = BitVec('x0',2) and x1 = BitVec('x1',2), x0+x1==2 gives the solution 3 and 3 as 3+3%4=2, I add in contraints saying they can be no more than 2.

```
x0 = BitVec('x0',2)
x1 = BitVec('x1',2)
g = Goal()
g.add(x0 + x1 == 2)
g.add(x0 <= 2)
g.add(x1 <= 2)
```

This gives no solution

I have also tried the following

```
x0 = BitVec('x0',3)
x1 = BitVec('x1',3)
g = Goal()
g.add(x0 + x1 == 2)
g.add(x0 <= 2)
g.add(x1 <= 2)
```

Which gives the wrong solution x0 = 6, x1 = 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is `unsat`, because of the domain of 2-bit bit-vectors can only encode `-2`, `-1`, `0`, and `1`:

```
  Bits|Value
  ----+------
    00| 0
    01| 1
    10|-2
    11|-1
```

In z3py `<=` does a *signed* comparison. So, when you say `x0 <= 2`, that right hand-side `2` is actually `-2` (see the bit pattern above.) So, you restricted the values to be `<= -2`, and there's only one such value in the domain, i.e., `-2`. And `-2 + -2 = 0` when you do modular arithmetic (modulo 4), i.e., there's no value that satisfies your requirement that `x0 + x1` should be `2`. So, you get `unsat` as answer.

Your second try is similar. In this case you have 3-bits, so the valid values are `-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3`. (You should write down the bit-patterns corresponding to this to convince yourself.) I'll let you work-out the details. Note that, unlike what you reported, I see:

```
[x1 = 2, x0 = 0]
```

as the answer, and that actually is the correct answer in this case. I'm not sure why you're seeing `x0=6, x1=4`; maybe you had some other code running.

Remember that in SMTLib, bit-vectors are unsigned, but operations are. In particular, comparisons. If your intention was to simply use unsigned bit-vectors (i.e., a 2-bit vector representing `0`,`1`,`2`, and `3`), then you should use the correct comparison operator:

```py
from z3 import *

x0 = BitVec('x0',2)
x1 = BitVec('x1',2)

s = Solver()
s.add(x0 + x1 == 2)
s.add(ULE(x0, 2))
s.add(ULE(x1, 2))

if s.check() == sat:
  print(s.model())
else:
  print("No solution")
```

This prints:

```
[x1 = 0, x0 = 2]
```

which is probably what you were going for. Note the use of the correct comparison operator `ULE`, which does unsigned-less-than-or-equal, instead of `<=`, which does a signed comparison.